# Restore TeamCity deleted build configuration

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to restore accidentally deleted build configuration on TeamCity 9.X following this article "https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/How+To...#HowTo...-RestoreJustDeletedProject"
However, I cannot find _trash folder under /config

I'm running TC on Windows and using internal DB.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of TeamCity are you running and how long ago was the build configuration deleted?

Comment: TeamCity version 9.1.6 and build configuration has been deleted 10 hours ago